# Outlook VBA stops functioning the next day

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have VBA code in Outlook I use to send specific emails (with three asterics in the subject line) to the deleted folder after sent in  'This Outlook Session'.

It works correctly when Outlook is first opened, and all day long, however, the next day I find at some point overnight the VBA code has failed to function and only functions properly again if I close \ re-open Outlook??

This only started to occur when the company moved to the 2007 & 2010 versions.

I need it to run constantly on sent mail as I have early am batch processes that send out a lot of emails that I want to have removed from sent folder and placed in the deleted folder after eachis sent as this code does.

Here is the code.  Since it worked well before, I can only assume the newer Outlook versions need some additional trigger to keep 'This Outlook Session' open or something of that nature.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents olSentItems As Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As NameSpace
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olSentItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub
Private Sub olSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If Item.Class = olMail And InStr(1, Trim(Item.Subject), " * * * ", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
Then
Item.Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at the Trust Center Settings >> Macros.  Office 2003 has it in a different way and it is all new after Office 2003.

Try different settings and see which one fits your need.  They are totally four setting levels.

Also it is good idea to use only one version of Outlook.  Don't interchange between 2007 and 2010 if you have both of them.  Outlook versions cannot co exist with creation of bugs.

This page should be able to give me more details.

[Click Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-documents-HA010031071.aspx#BM13)